# Handling unchecked IPC messages

Tags: node.js

I am using ZMQ (ZeroMQ) for IPC -

If I can get a message, I want to handle that message, routing it to the desired handler function, either a function named **`one`** or **`two`** (or `three`).

```
var messageHandler = {

one: function(msg){},
two: function(msg){}

}
```

Now, there are two ways I know of doing this:

I could put in a bunch of **`case`** statements like so:

```
reply.on('message',function(msg){

  switch(msg){
    case 'one':
     messageHandler.one(msg);
     break;
    case 'two':
     messageHandler.two(msg);
    break; 
    default:
     ///
    }
}
```

or I could got with more of a shorthand approach like so:

```
reply.on('message',function(msg){

  if(typeof messageHandler[msg]=='function'){
                messageHandler[msg](msg);
            } else{
                throw new Error('no handler error');
        }

}
```

is there a good reason to use one but not the other?

Comment: I would stick with second as it saves you from having to add a case to the switch if you add another message eg."third"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems clear that the best way to do it is the second way:

```
 if(typeof messageHandler[msg]=='function'){
                messageHandler[msg](msg);
            } else{
                throw new Error('no handler error');
        }
```

the reasons being:

1. smaller code base
2. the program matches the input ('msg' var) and output (the matching on non-matching function name)
   pre-emptively, without having to maintain the case statements.

Comment: How is such "open-ended" system vulnerable to a **`msg`**-content based **security**, once an "unwanted" handler is easily reach-able for **any black-hacker attack** just by meeting the `=='function'` condition?

Comment: hello, I don't see how that is any different than the case statement approach. all advantages but no disadvantages. I suppose some sort of authentication might be necessary for server requests. case statements don't seem to be any better. I am on a private network so not worried about security, but if this were a public service, yeah...